# Coolant leaking from the back of motor between firewall

Tags: coolant, leak

2001 Nissan  Xterra 3.3 v6 I can see the coolant  drip on the ground but cannot see where it is coming from,  any ideas suggestions? , also it overheats and does not replenish from the over flow. Please help

Comment: I would suggest you slide under the car and figure out where the coolant is leaking from. It could be as minor as a loose hose clamp, as slightly less minor as a cracked hose, or as major as a cracked block. Either way, this is NOT the kind of problem you want to ignore - the only way to fix it is to find the source of the leak. Good luck!

Comment: on the 3.3 there's a coolant tube that runs under the intake manifold. the heater hoses run off that tube as well. check the clamps and hoses.

Comment: I looked under and saw a 5/8" open ended  hose that it looks like the coolant is coming from. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a photo?

Comment: Yes, first thing in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that it is from the heater hose that goes from the engine to your cabin A/C.  The overheating is from the lack of pressure due to the leakage and air getting into the system.  The lack of renewing from the overflow container - same thing - when the system is cooling down and normally the pressure drops - then it normally sucks back in coolant from the overflow. Since there is leakage, there isn't a drop in pressure.

If this is the case, you should be able to track it down, check the hose clamps.  If you are in a temperate zone, you should be able to run a hose to bypass the A/C if the leak is within the cabin and you don't feel like tearing out the dash to get at it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is coolant, the hose you describe sounds more like the A/C condensate drain.

The overheating is another problem…

Answer (score 0):

It is none of the above . Between fire wall and engine there is a hose 5/8 it's called by pass hose it's in tight place takes time to replace we have done it.